# How do you detect words that start with “@” or “#” within an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, nsstring, uitextview

I'm building a Twitter iPhone app, and it needs to detect when you enter a hashtag or @-mention within a string in a UITextView.

How do I find all words preceded by the "@" or "#" characters within an NSString?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you need to get those characters during editing or after editing(maybe by calling an action)? according to this point i may help you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class with a pattern like #\w+ (\w stands for word characters).

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString* word = [string substringWithRange:wordRange];
    NSLog(@"Found tag %@", word);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Twitter recently updated the hashtag filters, and now supports only certain non-latin characters. For example, you won't match Arabic hashtags.

Comment: That should be `\\w+` and not just `\w+`.

Comment: what is the significance of + ?

Comment: More adequate pattern for Twitter hashtags would be @"(^|\\W)(#|\\uFF03)(\\w*\\p{L}\\w*)". It does not match things like "one#two" and "We're #1" and works fine for non-ASCII letters.

Comment: @VadimYelagin Can you share how you used the twitter-text-java regex on Objective-C/iOS?

Comment: I haven't. The URL is for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can break a string into pieces (words) by using componentsSeparatedByString: and then check the first character of each one.

Or, if you need to do it while the user is typing, you can provide a delegate for the text view and implement textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: to see typed characters.

Comment: Defining word boundaries is always going to be application-specific. componentsSeparatedByString: is a decent technique but the programmer still has to make decisions about "either/or" and "A1" and "neo-conservative" and a bunch of other constructions.

Comment: Implemented this similarly below. You've got a point about word boundaries though. One could conceivably have hashtags like I #like/#love this. Hm....

Answer (score 1):

Made a category of NSString for that. It's very simple: Find all words, return all words that start with # to get the hashtags.

Relevant code segment below - rename those methods & the category too...

```
@implementation NSString (PA)
// all words in a string
-(NSArray *)pa_words {
    return [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
}

// only the hashtags
-(NSArray *)pa_hashTags {
    NSArray *words = [self pa_words];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSString *word in words) {
        if ([word hasPrefix:@"#"])
            [result addObject:word];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([[test substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"@"] ||
   [[test substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"#"])
{
    bla blah blah
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check that the text is longer than 1 before doing substring operations. Otherwise some user will enter an empty message and be mad when the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it using `NSPredicate`

You can try something like this in the UITextView delegate:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    _words = [self.textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] '@'"];
    NSArray* names = [_words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (_oldArray)
    {
        NSMutableSet* set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:names];
        NSMutableSet* set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:_oldArray];
        [set1 minusSet:set2];
        if (set1.count > 0)
            NSLog(@"Results %@", set1);
    }
    _oldArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:names];
}
```

where _words, _searchResults and _oldArray are NSArrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use following expression to detect @ or # in string

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(#(\\w+)|@(\\w+)) " options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```