# Find and detect "@" and "#" with NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to find "@" and "#" sign in my text with `NSRegularExpression` like that;

```
NSString *testString = @"This text contains @ and # signs";
NSRange stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [testString length]);
NSRegularExpression *regexTest = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"\\b(@|#)\\b"];
NSRange nameRange = [regexTest rangeOfFirstMatchInString:testString options:0 range:stringRange];
```

When i NSLog `nameRange.location`, it's always return 0. What is the correct form to find that signs with `NSRegularExpression`?

Comment: Sorry it's copy/paste error, i fixed it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353567/how-do-you-detect-words-that-start-with-or-within-an-nsstring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it using `NSPredicate`. This tells you the current @mention word that's being edited/typed. Hope this helps.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    _words = [self.textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] '@'"];
    NSArray* names = [_words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (_oldArray)
    {
        NSMutableSet* set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:names];
        NSMutableSet* set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:_oldArray];
        [set1 minusSet:set2];
        if (set1.count > 0)
            NSLog(@"Results %@", set1);
    }
    _oldArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:names];
}
```