# Regex to get strings between URLs and hashtags iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string like

```
Hello, I'm #codebot, newbie to the department of http://department.orc.com under #george who is in http://www.orc.com
```

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to get all non-hashtag and non-url string from this string. And is there a way to get strings like,

**normal texts**

```
Hello, I'm 
, newbie to the department of
under 
 who is in
```

**URLs**

```
http://department.orc.com
http://www.orc.com
```

**hastags**

```
#codebot
#george
```

Please suggest me a way to get these 3 kind of data in separate arrays.

Comment: try these regex obviously go perfected 1)http(s|)://[^ \n]* 2)#[^ ,\.\n#]*

Comment: Thanks. But 1) gives me urls. and the 2) says invalid escape character. Is it possible to combine these regex together ?

Comment: [How can I extract a URL from a sentence that is in a NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4590440) [How do you detect words that start with # within an NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10353567)

Comment: These 2 for search #tags and urls. Then how can I get the non-hastag and non-url strings with the existing order.

Comment: If you had a box full of different colored balls and a robot that would dig around in the box and hand you all the orange balls, how would you get all the non-orange ones?